# Luggage storage at Frankfurt Airport, can someone else pick up the bag?

Tags: airports, luggage-storage, frankfurt

Is there a way to have one person store a bag at the Frankfurt Airport and another person retrieve it? Or does it require the same key to open the locker?

I am leaving a bag with a friend but we are missing each other at the airport on the same day, so the bag will be stored for a couple of hours.

Comment: There are AFAIK no luggage lockers at all at Frankfurt Airport, only staffed luggage storage offices. Without being sure about the details, I would assume that you get a paper receipt when depositing items there and that you will actually need that receipt to get your stuff back out.

Answer (score 2):

In [this page](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/content/airport-content/article/en/travel/luggage/storage.html) you have the airport information. It seems that you need a receipt but maybe you can call to one of these numbers and they can find a solution of you:

> Terminal 1, between Concourses B and C, Level 2 (Departures), open daily from 6 a.m. to 10 p.m., phone +49 69 690 73277
>
> Terminal 1, Concourse B, Level 1 (Arrivals), open daily 24/7 hours, phone +49 69 690 70786
>
> Terminal 2, Concourse D, Level 2 (Arrivals), open daily from 6 a.m. to 10 p.m., phone +49 69 690 72860